# Ordering values by custom criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

I have two tables A and B table:

Table - A - represents basic information of persons

```
emp_id |      email       | name
----------------------------------------
 1     | abc@gmail.com    |   john
 2     | dbc@gmail.com    |   john1
 3     | cbc@gmail.com    |   john2
 4     | xbc@gmail.com    |   john3
 5     | xac@gmail.com    |   john4
```

Table - B represents the locations handled by persons

john is handling Region and Zone
john1 is handling Area and Territory and so on...

Sequence of locationType is as follows : Region->Zone->Area->Territory
Regions is having higher priority then comes zone and so on..

```
id | emp_id | locationType
--------------------
 1 | 1     |   Region
 2 | 2     |   Area
 3 | 3     |   Area
 4 | 4     |   Territory
 5 | 1     |   Zone
 6 | 2     |   Territory
 7 | 5     |   Zone
 8 | 5     |   Area
```

I want to fetch those persons who are handling the higher locationType.
Suppose john is handling Region and zone so i want to display Region as Region is of higher priority and similarly john1 is handling Territory and Area so i want to display only Area as because Area is of higher priority

My Desired Output:

```
 id | emp_id |   name   |   locationType 
----------------------------------------
 1  | 1      |   john   |   Region
 5  | 5      |   john4  |   Zone
 3  | 3      |   john1  |   Area
 4  | 4      |   john2  |   Area
 4  | 4      |   john3  |   Territory
```

What I am getting

```
 id | emp_id |   name   |   locationType 
----------------------------------------
 1  | 1      |   john   |   Region
 1  | 1      |   john   |   Zone
 5  | 5      |   john4  |   Zone
 5  | 5      |   john4  |   Area
 2  | 2      |   john1  |   Area
 3  | 3      |   john2  |   Area
 4  | 4      |   john3  |   Territory
 4  | 4      |   john3  |   Territory
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is there a location type table where you store the relative positions?

Comment: @SalmanA only two tables i have

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i am able to get the data but not on the priority basis as i want john region to be shown i am getting john for both Region and Zone

Answer (score 2):

You can use `field()` to turn the locations into numbers.  What you want is the minimum location based on this ordering.

You can obtain this information per employee using a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*
from b
where field(b.locationType, 'Region', 'Zone', 'Area', 'Territory') =
       (select min(field(b2.locationType, 'Region', 'Zone', 'Area', 'Territory'))
        from b b2
        where b2.emp_id = b.emp_id
       );
```

Adding the extra columns from `a` is just a matter of joining in the table.

Comment: there are two tables and location_type is avaliable in one table that ie table B

Comment: Using field() only

Comment: @GauravMasand you'll need to join but the idea, that of using field function and min, is correct.

Comment: @GauravMasand . . . You only need one table to get the "highest" region for an employee.  As the answer points out, the rest of the information can be brought in using a `join`.  That does not seem like an interesting part of the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...please have a look at my desired table... john is handling two locations Region and Zone what i want is the Region row to be displayed because this is howmy desired output will look like.
Region is having higher priority and so john is handling both region and zone i want to do display that locationCode which is having higher priority.

Comment: @GauravMasand . . . That is what this query does.

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` in order clause

```
order by (case locationType when 'Region' then 1
                when 'Zone' then 2
                when 'Area' then 3
                   when 'Territory' then 4
                   else 5  end )
```

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve the Issue Pemanently just Follow the following steps. It will help you in data normalization also.

1 Create A new table  that has LocaitonType name and id and Insert your location type as the order you want.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_C](
[LocationType_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](50) NULL )    

 Insert Into [Table_C] (name) values('Region')
 Insert Into [Table_C] (name) values('Zone')
 Insert Into [Table_C] (name) values('Area')
 Insert Into [Table_C] (name) values('Territory')
```

2.Alter your table b **LocationType** column Data type to int.

```
    Alter Table Table_B 
    Alter column locationType int not null
```

3. Now Insert id from Table_c to Table_B Locationtype Column.
   and use the below query to get the desired output.

Select Table_B.id,Table_A.emp_id,Table_A.name,Table_C.name as locationType from Table_B inner join Table_A on Table_A.emp_id=Table_B.emp_id
inner join Table_C on Table_C.LocationType_Id=Table_B.locationType 
order by Table_C.LocationType_Id